# How i can display values on PIE chart in angular ? i am using ngx-echarts

Tags: angular, echarts, ngx-echarts

This is my options for my echarts, i don't know where to add an options to display value of my data on the pie chart .  or any indicators to display values without hover event.

```
 this.options = {
  backgroundColor: this.eTheme.bg,
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'item',
    formatter: '{b} : {c}',
  },
  legend: {
    orient: 'vertical',
    left: 'left',
    data: [],
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Users',
      type: 'pie',
      radius: '50%',
      center: ['50%', '70%'],
      data: [],
    },
  ],
};
```

[my pie chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzdh6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no option to directly display the value on the chart, you'll have to use the label formatter to do this.

For example:

```js
 this.options = {
  backgroundColor: this.eTheme.bg,
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'item',
    formatter: '{b} : {c}',
  },
  legend: {
    orient: 'vertical',
    left: 'left',
    data: [],
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Users',
      type: 'pie',
      label: {
          formatter: '{a|{a}}{abg|}\n{hr|}\n  {b|{b}：}{c}  {per|{d}%}  '
      },
      radius: '50%',
      center: ['50%', '70%'],
      data: [],
    },
  ],
};
```

You can adapt your formatter as you see fit.

Comment: i see , thank you so much , it's ok , i just need to display values without doing a hover event on the chart